# What ASIC/MCU is in my keyboard?

Tags: microcontroller, identification, encoder, keyboard, asic

I disassembled my unbranded USB keyboard to find out what ASIC/encoder/MCU is inside. The chip is (as expected) covered, like the following example:

[image]

How to find out which chip is underneath?

Comment: You're unlikely to figure it out and if you do you are unlikely to be able to buy one or get any information one one. Instead, look for "keyboard USB controller" open source projects  online if you are trying to make your own keyboard

Comment: So what's to be done after, if at all you managed to find out?

Comment: They put epoxy on them specifically so you can't find out... You can try removing the epoxy, but you'll likely damage the chip in the process (if it's even marked).

Comment: *Why* do you need to know it?

Comment: To be sure it's an OTP chip that can't be tampered with.

Comment: @FPU OK, so you are concerned about the possibility that some kind of keylogger can be programmed into it.

Comment: Keyboard readers don’t usually have the intelligence to do much more than read key states and none properly do n-key rollover after 2 keys when it is the next one released that is sent, not the order pressed.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Unless it is a specially designed keyboard for spying purposes :)

Comment: The spy also has to be in the motherboard to link any extraneous info.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Or it might have a tiny wireless transmitter embedded :)

Comment: No Keyboard Trojans, viruses or loggers have been reported to date.  https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/heres-a-list-of-29-different-types-of-usb-attacks/

Comment: @EugeneSh. and using 5V loop for an antenna.

Comment: Number 25 on that list: DFU. In some modern keyboards you can find AVR or even ARM chips with flash memory. Often the firmware can be updated by just running an executable. So these chips can be put in DFU mode without manual interaction like pulling a DIP switch or shorting a few pins or whatever. Maybe such keyboards could be turned into BadUSB devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assembly is likely done as a 'chip on board' to save cost. There's nothing evil about that - it's a very common technique in consumer electronics.

How to ID the chip then? Ask the USB interface itself: device endpoint enumeration will give both a vendor and device ID and possibly other info like version, etc., which can at least very much narrow down the possible chips that may be in use. No need to take the epoxy off.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing to find out is to decapsulate the chip by dissolving the epoxy and taking die shots of the silicon chip under a microscope.

The die shot can reveal markings about the chip, or perhaps it can be reverse-engineerd to figure out what it could be.

Highly unlikely though that this will reveal the identity of the chip, and even if it does reveal it, it is unknown what would be the usefulness to know it, given that microcontrollers available for purchase could perform the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Another method that can shed some light is to use a multimeter and test the PCB pins on a DC voltage scale with respect to ground (while it's plugged into a host computer).
The black wire of the USB is ground.
The key switch pins will be the row of 26+ parallel contacts near the edge of the PCB that mate with the switch membrane contacts.

Keyboards use a row and column matrix to read the key switches.
The output pins (often the rows) should show a positive voltage near 5 volts.
The input pins (often columns) will show very little or no voltage.

Once you have found all pins with positive voltage near 5 volts you can get an idea for the general layout of the input/output matrix of the MCU - 8x18 (8 outputs and 18 inputs), 8x20, etc.
The MCUs will have i/o pins directly matching these layouts.

Using a pen and paper, or a spreadsheet, you can map out the key matrix noting which keystrokes appear (use notepad, or a keytest app) on the host  computer by shorting an output pin with an input pin briefly.

You can search for MCUs by layout (8x18, etc) and see if the datasheets have a matching key matrix.

Sometimes you can get lucky and the MCU name is printed on the PCB (Dell's L100 keyboard PCB had HT82K629 printed on it:
A Holtek USB HID keyboard MCU.)